# Issues simulating LC oscillator circuit in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, oscillator

I'm on a quest to simulate various circuits in LTspice that are a part of an Elenco project kit. All has been going well until I started trying to simulate some simple oscillator circuits.

In the project you close a switch to turn on the +9VDC from a battery to start the oscillator which I'm simulating by using a pulse. I should be seeing a roughly 2Hz oscillation going though the LED while the 9V is applied, but it isn't working in LTSpice.
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

The inductors are from the primary side of a transformer. The project booklet gave the values of 300mH from one end to the other with a center tap that divides the inductance in half. I measured a series resistance through each inductor of around 90 ohms so I added that in case it would help. I'm not sure exactly what types of LEDs or transistors they used in the project. At the very least I know the transistor is a BPJ NPN.

Link to the .asc
https://github.com/mmprkdev/LTspice/blob/main/Oscillator.asc

Thanks!

Comment: Joule thieves rely on saturation of the magnetic core which you didn't simulate.

Comment: Also, if L1 and L2 are on the same core, then LTspice needs to be told these are coupled.  Add a `K1 L1 L2 0.99` operation (.op button) to the schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a coupling factor between the coils. Add spice directive `K L1 L2 0.99` (or a similar coupling factor slightly less than 1).

C1 is too large. Reduce it to ~8 μF.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I had to couple those inductors.

Comment: Is it normal to see those spikes of -3kV for each oscillation on the base of the transistor?

Comment: Yes, it's normal to see such anomalies in LTspice, because most transistor models don't include the Base-Emitter reverse breakdown characteristic. You can simulate it with a diode and 6.8V zener wired in series to limit reverse voltage to ~-7.5V. For more realistic results you should also add inductor core loss (simulate it with parallel resistance) and capacitance.